# Get data-val on a programatically added <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get an programatically added `li` `data-val` on click, as below:

```
$(function () {
  $("#bpadd").click(function () {
      var bpinput = document.getElementById("bpinput").value;
      $('#bpitem').append('<li data-val="' + bpinput + '  clicked">' + bpinput + '</li>');
  });

  $('#bpitem li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('data-val'));
  });
```

This is the `html` sample:

```
<input type="text" id="bpinput">
<input type="button" id="bpadd" value="+">    
<ul id="bpitem">
    <li data-val="Test 1 clicked">Test 1</li>
</ul>
```

If I click in `Test 1`, it works, but nothing happens when I click in a new item, why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `.on`<sup>[doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/)</sup> function on some selector that'll work for every newly added element, like this:

```
$('#bpitem').on('click', 'li', function () {
  alert($(this).attr('data-val'));
});
```

As you can see on the docs, the function will bind the events on newly-added elements that match the selector rather than just binding it to existing ones like the `.click` function does.

Comment: Hi... sorry but I can't run this code... 
Could you help me to check it? http://jsfiddle.net/fabiobraglin/7gggw9Lp/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#bpitem').on('click', 'li', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('data-val'));
});
```

The `.click()` method binds the click handler only to elements that exist at the time that line of code runs. If you use `.on()`, you bind the handler to your parent `#bpitem` element (which exists initially) but when a click occurs jQuery checks if the clicked child element matches the selector in the second parameter and thus it works on children of `#bpitem` that were added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#bpitem').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert('clicked');
);
```

This will dynamically add event listeners to ALL bpitem li elements instead of the ones that are there when this is first ran